# How to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu on GPT disk

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, windows-7

Hi I am trying to install windows 7 on my laptop do a bit of work using a tool only available on Windows.. but keep getting the error message:

*"Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is not of the GPT partition style"*

I have Ubuntu currently installed but nothing else and have created space for the Windows installation using GParted.

I don't have a disk drive so have created a bootable USB with Windows 7 on it.

I have tried zeroing the free partition space and converting it to NTFS but they both didnt work.

Has anybody got a solution to the problem? Kind regards.

Comment: And your reason for thinking the Windows message is wrong and that you are in fact, using GPT is?

Answer (score 4):

Windows ties its boot partition table type (MBR vs. GPT) to its boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI), so if the disk is pre-partitioned, the boot mode must match the existing partition table.

Your question is inconsistent about the current partition table: The question title says you're using GPT, but the quoted error message indicates that the disk is *not* GPT. My memory (and a Google search) suggests that this error message normally lacks the negation, so I suspect you've mis-quoted it. If so, then the problem is that you've booted Windows in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. The solution is to boot in EFI/UEFI mode. This can be difficult, because the Windows 7 disc doesn't always want to boot in EFI mode. (But see below for a suggestion.) Also, in order to do this, your computer must have EFI firmware. This option is common in computers sold in the last 2-2.5 years, but is uncommon on older computers. If you've got a BIOS-only computer, you have only four options, AFAIK:

- Use a second disk for Windows. This second disk can use MBR, while the existing one can use GPT. Note that Windows can use a GPT disk as a *data disk* even on a BIOS-based computer; it just can't *boot* from a GPT disk in BIOS mode.
- Convert the disk from GPT to MBR. You can do this with `gdisk`; see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) for details. Note that you'll need to re-install GRUB after doing this conversion, and there are other caveats described on that page, so read it thoroughly and be prepared!
- Use [DUET](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/index.html) or [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/) to add an EFI as a BIOS-mode boot loader. This is awkward in many ways, and it's unlikely to work if you've got an AMD CPU, but it might be worth considering if you're desperate enough.
- Use a [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) to make Windows see the disk as an MBR disk, even while Linux uses the GPT. As the linked-to page details, though, hybrid MBRs are ugly and dangerous, so I consider this the worst of the four options, absent further information that would rule out both of the other three.

If I've misinterpreted and the disk is actually MBR, then you've got the opposite problem; but it's likely to be easier to coax the Windows installation disc into booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Usually this can be done by using the computer's built-in boot manager, which you can usually access by pressing Esc or a function key early in the boot process. With any luck, you'll see two options for the optical disc, one with "EFI" or "UEFI" in its description and one without. Use the EFI/UEFI option to boot in that mode, and the other one to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.